# NullPointerException while using oteleporter with config file

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to import tables from RDBMS with a JSON config file which stated the edge relationship. But when I am trying to run the command, it throws a NullPointerException.

Command -

```
oteleporter.bat -jdriver mysql -jurl jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive_catalog_test_db -juser root -jpasswd root -ourl plocal:C:\Users\ME\desktop\OrientDB\orientdb-community-importers-2.2.27\databases\HiveCatalog_D02_TeleTest -s naive -nr java -v 1 -include "tbls,columns_v2" -conf "C:\Users\ME\desktop\Catalog_POC\Inheritance_and_edge_loaders\migration-config.json"
```

Exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.orientechnologies.teleporter.context.OTeleporterContext.printExceptionMessage(OTeleporterContext.java:152)
at com.orientechnologies.teleporter.util.OMigrationConfigManager.loadMigrationConfigFromFile(OMigrationConfigManager.java:64)
at com.orientechnologies.teleporter.main.OTeleporter.execute(OTeleporter.java:250)
at com.orientechnologies.teleporter.main.OTeleporter.main(OTeleporter.java:219)
```

However, when I am running the command without the config attribute, it is executing fine.

Sample JSON -

```
{
  "edges": [
    {
      "HasColumns": {
        "mapping": {
          "fromTable": "Tbls",
          "fromColumns": ["tbId"],
          "toTable": "ColumnsV2",
          "toColumns": ["cdId"],
          "direction": "direct"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your json config file of course. Maybe the path is wrong?
By the way, you can enjoy a new visual tool in order to build your custom configuration. You can find it in the server management area of Studio.

Here is the doc link:
https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Studio-Teleporter.html

Good luck!